# Detect first change in column value results

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to get a divider in am automated select menu.

Now, when a fieldname changes value from 0 to 1, I want to detect that and insert a data-divider.

This is what I have so far, but it repeats for all the 1-value occurences.

```
fieldname 0
fieldname 0
fieldname 0
[here should the change be detected and the divider inserted]
fieldname 1
fieldname 1
fieldname 1
```

this code generates a divider above all the 1 values:

```
if($fieldname == "1") {
    $output .= "<option data-divider=\"true\">------------</option>"; 
}
```

anyone know how to break out of this after the first one is found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the state that the output has printed the data divider

```
$printed = false;
foreach ($loopingLogic) {
  // normal option logic
  if ($fieldname === '1' && !$printed) {
    $output .= '<option>..</option>';
    $printed = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: This would only work for 1 field name change. What if there are multiple different fields?

Comment: @x3ns in that case you would just make $printed an array, and check for the the existence of the $fieldname in that array.

Comment: Guys, can I do a follow up on my question here? I tried the code @BenRowe explained here, but it doesn't seem to work when I change $printed into an array and do array search.

Comment: Nevermind that one above. @Parsa actually had the answer to this one below.

Answer (score 1):

Before the loop:

```
$last_fieldname = '';
```

Inside the loop:

```
if (empty($last_fieldname))
    $last_fieldname = $fieldname;

if ($fieldname != $last_fieldname) {
    $output .= "<option data-divider=\"true\">------------</option>";
    $last_fieldname = $fieldname;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The php `break;` statement should work.

Assuming you have this in a loop of some sort:

```
if($fieldname == "1") {
  $output .= "<option data-divider=\"true\">------------</option>"; 
  break; //should stop the loop from processing further.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, tried this one but stopped the rest of the query,

Answer (score 0):

### Simple Method:

Keep track of the previous number with the tracking variable outside the the main loop.

i.e.

```
// Outside the loop, and $fields being the array you will traverse through
$previousUniqueFieldName = key(reset($fields));

for ($fields as $fieldName => $fieldValue) {

    // Inside the loop:
    if($fieldname != $previousUniqueFieldName) {
        $output .= "<option data-divider=\"true\">------------</option>";
        $previousUniqueFieldName = $fieldName;
    }
}
```